# 80s-90s horror movie about opening a gate to a hellish dimension

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

A group of people/students opens a portal to a hell dimension (by summoning an alternate reality) in a building (attic/loft) (through spells, I think). After that, they can't leave the building because there are creatures outside. One by one is then killed. One guy puts his head out and it is instantly ripped off.

At the end, only two remain and are forced to leave the building and live in that nightmarish new world.

Comment: Was this [found footage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Found_footage_(film_technique)) or shot like a standard film? (There seem to be a lot of found footage movies with a similar premise to this.) Also, do you recall what sort of building it was?

Comment: It was a standard film. As I recall it, the building wasnt ever shown from outside.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what were the character's names? Were there any memorable actors? Were they male or female? How did they learn how to make a portal? What did the portal look like? Was there overt nudity/gore in the film? What did the creatures look like? Were they physical effects or animations? Was the whole film set in the attic aside from the start and end?

Comment: I was younger I can't recall it. There where I think 5 or 6 people, maybe 2 girls.

Comment: I read a summary about people being in a building and one of them (a blonde woman) getting possessed by the devil to make a ritual to make him come back. But the whole story was resolved by the end of the movie, so it's unlikely to be it.

Comment: The end of the movie is similar to Cabin in the Woods, it's like there is no return and the scene cuts there (dystopian end, no living creature), at first I thought it was Demons 1 or Night of the Demons, but the end isn't

Comment: The movie I was thinking about was this one. I don't think it's the one but still sharing just in case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Darkness_(film)

Comment: No, it isn't either but thanks appreciate it.

Comment: @Alen - In roughly which year did you actually watch this? I ask, because there have been instances where someone said a film they were asking about came out within a given period, but it turned out that it was released significantly later than the range they indicated.

Comment: In the late 90s have I watched ones and than across 2005 once more.

Comment: DEMONS 2 (1986) takes place entirely in an apartment building and has a similarly apocalyptic ending.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [They Found Hell](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5113926/) (2015)?

A group of students in a building open a portal to hell, accidentally trapping themselves inside.

> A group of college students accidentally discover hell after their teleportation experiment goes wrong. The dwellers of the underworld torture and kill them one by one to steal their souls.

Comment: No, the whole story is placed in this building/loft.

Answer (score -1):

Is it "[*From Beyond*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091083/)"?

> A group of scientists have developed the Resonator, a machine which
> allows whoever is within range to see beyond normal perceptible
> reality. But when the experiment succeeds, they are immediately
> attacked by terrible life forms.

Comment: I don't know, is it?  Can you please explain why you think the answer is *From Beyond*, and how it matches the question?  You might want to read [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Prince of Darkness? I was trying to figure out the name of a movie similar to what you described and it was Prince of Darkness that I was looking for.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is a match?